# How do I move a file with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

I want to move a file with Ruby. How do I do that?

Answer (score 291, accepted):

You can use [FileUtils](https://ruby-doc.org/current/stdlibs/fileutils/FileUtils.html) to do this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.mv('/tmp/your_file', '/opt/new/location/your_file')
```

Remember; if you are moving across partitions, "mv" will copy the file to new destination and unlink the source path.

Comment: I forgot to add that you can not move across partitions. Thanks.

Comment: Actually mv does the copy for you. 
"Moves file(s) src to dest. If file and dest exist on the different disk partition, the file is copied instead." ... http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/FileUtils.html#M004330

Comment: can you confirm if the file is deleted after being copied from a different partition?

Answer (score 98):

An old question, i'm surprised no one answered this simple solution. You don't need fileutils or a systemcall, just rename the file to the new location.

```
File.rename source_path, target_path
```

Happy coding

Comment: File rename won't work across partitions, and throws the error "Invalid cross-device link". FileUtils is a better choice in those cases, but for a simple move in the same partition, rename works.

Comment: @d3vkit, thanks vor the remark but in windows this works across drives, local and remote, eg <code>File.rename 'c:/test/test.txt', 'e:/test.txt'</code>, what OS do you use ?

Comment: Ah, I had trouble specifically in Ubuntu using some Windows networked shares. I also ended up having trouble with FileUtils.mv, which would move the file and then say it didn't have permission to delete the old file. I ended up using FileUtils.cp and then File.delete to get rid of the old file.

Comment: This definitely does not work across partition on linux. I guess it depends on the underlying OS APIs. To be sure, just use `FileUtils.mv`.

Comment: Note in some cases you may *want* to restrict to the same partition, as I'm doing right now to ensure an atomic operation.

Comment: @ Zorg Agreed if you mean to use cross platform, if other partition and  ![OS]  =~ Windows require 'fileutils'; FileUtils.mv or something like that, anyway I would always try and catch in moving a file and in such case I also would rather use FileUtils right away

Answer (score 16):

[FileUtils.move](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv)

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.move 'stuff.rb', '/notexist/lib/ruby'
```

Comment: +1 Note that .move is an alias of .mv so you should be able to do FileUtils.mv too.

Comment: I don't. `mv` makes me feel like I'm in my beloved console ;)

Comment: And the nice thing about Ruby is that it has both `move` and `mv`so one can pick either one. :)

Comment: Should be `require "fileutils"` (no caps)

Answer (score 10):

Use the module 'fileutils' and use FileUtils.mv:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv

Comment: This is why we should be posting the answer and then providing a link for credit/resource.

Answer (score 2):

here is a template .

```
 src_dir = "/full_path/to_some/ex_file.txt"

 dst_dir = "/full_path/target_dir"

 #Use the method below to do the moving
 move_src_to_target_dir(src_dir, dst_dir)



 def archive_src_to_dst_dir(src_dir, dst_dir)

     if File.exist ? (src_dir)

     puts "about to move this file:  #{src_dir}"

     FileUtils.mv(src_dir, dst_dir)
 else

     puts "can not find source file to move"

 end
 end
```

Answer (score -10):

you can move your file like this

Rails.root.join('foo','bar')

Comment: That's the answer to the question "How do I build a path/filename relative to the root directory of a Rails project?". It doesn't move anything.