# Storing images in filesystem is breaking the files. Is there a better way to write this? Why do I get broken files?

Tags: ruby, image, post, file-upload, sinatra

```
post '/upload' do
  unless params[:file] && (tmpfile = params[:file][:tempfile]) && (name = params[:file][:filename])
    return haml(:upload)
  end
  time = Time.now.to_s
  time.gsub!(/\s/, '')
  name = time + name
  while blk = tmpfile.read(65536)
    File.open(File.join(Dir.pwd,"public/uploads", name), "wb") { |f| f.write(tmpfile.read) }
  end
  'success'
end
```

Everything goes where expected the files just end up being corrupted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit looks really funky:

```
while blk = tmpfile.read(65536)
    File.open(File.join(Dir.pwd,"public/uploads", name), "wb") { |f| f.write(tmpfile.read) }
end
```

I'm guessing you're trying to read your tempfile a 65536-byte block at a time, and then write those blocks successively to your destination file.  But you never write `blk`, which is the first block you read; you write the rest of the file (`tempfile.read`) instead.  And even if this loop did write blocks like it should, it opens the file anew for each block, overwriting the old contents!  Anyway, I suspect you meant something like this:

```
File.open(File.join(Dir.pwd,"public/uploads", name), "wb") do |f|
    while(blk = tempfile.read(65536))
        f.write(blk)
    end
end
```

That said, if you've got the file as a temp file (presumably already on your local file system), maybe all you need to do is [move that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403239/how-do-i-move-file-with-ruby)?  It'll go way faster if that's the case - if the source and destination are on the same disk, it's just a matter of swapping some file system pointers, rather than copying all that data.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

The code opens and replaces the file during every iteration of the loop, which causes part of the problem. The code also reads the tmpfile into `blk` then throws that data away. Time.now.to_s contains colons, which is the path separator on Mac OS X, and could cause a problem on OS X. The user-supplied filename could contain some bad stuff like `..` which may allow users to overwrite files. Try this instead:

```
require 'pathname'
require 'zaru'

post '/upload' do
  unless tmpfile = params[:file].try(:[], :tempfile)
    return haml(:upload)
  end

  name = Zaru.sanitize!("#{Time.now.to_i}#{params[:file][:filename]}")
  Pathname.pwd.join("public/uploads", name).open("wb") do |f|
    while blk = tmpfile.read(65536)
      f.write(blk)
    end
  end

  'success'
end
```

You should also make sure that the filename doesn't end in something nefarious, like .js or .css, which could be exploited.