# Create a file in a specified directory

Tags: ruby, file-io

How can I create a new file in a specific directory. I created this class:

```
class FileManager

    def initialize()

    end

    def createFile(name,extension)
        return File.new(name <<"."<<extension, "w+")
    end
end
```

I would like to specify a directory (path) where to create the file. If this one doesn't exist, he will be created. So do I have to use `fileutils` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403239/how-do-i-move-a-file-with-ruby) just after file creation or can I specify directly in the creation the place where create the file?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. You can do `File.new("path/to/file")` or are you saying you want the directories created if they dont exist?

Comment: I would like the directory created if he doesn't exist. I edited my question

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following code checks that the directory you've passed in exists (pulling the directory from the path using `File.dirname`), and creates it if it does not. It then creates the file as you did before.

```
require 'fileutils'

def create_file(path, extension)
  dir = File.dirname(path)

  unless File.directory?(dir)
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir)
  end

  path << ".#{extension}"
  File.new(path, 'w')
end
```

Comment: So I have to use fileutils. Thanks for your answer