# How can I create a file on my desktop from a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, scripting

I'm building a webcrawler and I want it to output to a new file that is timestamped.  I've completed what I thought would be the more difficult part but I cannot seem to get it to save to the desktop.

```
Dir.chdir "~/Desktop"
dirname  = "scraper_out"
filename = "#{time}" 
Dir.mkdir(dirname) unless File.exists?(dirname) 
Dir.chdir(dirname)
File.new(filename, "w")
```

It errors out on the first line

```
`chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - ~/Desktop
```

I've read the documentation on FileUtils, File and cannot seem to find where people change into nested directories from the root.

Edit: I don't think FileUtils understands the ~.

Comment: Try `File.expand_path('~/Desktop')`

Comment: Wow, super helpful.  Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/` is not recognized by Ruby in this context.

Try:

```
Dir.chdir ENV['HOME']+"/Desktop"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you
[Create a file in a specified directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459879/create-a-file-in-a-specified-directory)