# How to transfer images from one folder to another in rails. (images are uploaded on s3 server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

How to transfer images from one folder to another in rails. (images are uploaded on s3 server)

Images are already upoded and needs to be transferred to some other folder, what is the best possible way to do this.

Comment: But this has absolutely nothing to do with Rails...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403239/how-do-i-move-a-file-with-ruby

duplicate

Comment: @MrBohr Not a duplicate. This question is about moving files **on Amazon S3**, not locally.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the right_aws gem will be of any help. https://github.com/rightscale/right_aws

Answer (score 0):

The best bet would be to use the ["move_to" method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#move_to-instance_method) in the AWS SDK.

Make sure you have the AWS SDK for Ruby - Version 2 installed:

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
```

Then, your command would look like this:

```
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new('source-bucket')
object = bucket.object('source-key')
object.move_to(bucket:'target-bucket', key:'target-key')
```