# Copying a file to a directory?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby program that copies a file from source folder to destination folder.

`C:\srcdir\testfile.txt` is the source folder, and `C:\targetdir` is the destination folder.

The program keeps reporting an error:

```
copy_files.rb:11:in block in <main>': uninitialized constant FileUtils (NameError)
```

Why is it? This is my code:

```
sourcedir = "C:\\srcdir"
targetdir = "C:\\targetdir"
Dir.foreach(sourcedir){
  |f|
  filepath = "#{sourcedir}\\#{f}"
  if !(File.directory?(filepath)) then
    if File.exist?("#{targetdir}\\#{f}") then
      puts("#{f} already exists in target directory (not copied)")
    else
      FileUtils.cp(filepath, targetdir)
      puts("Copying... #{filepath}")
    end
  end
}
```

Comment: You're writing extremely unidiomatic Ruby... See http://pastebin.com/Fz2kHgys

Comment: Can you give me advice? I don't understand you :)

Comment: Please read the start of the [IO documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html); Ruby makes it possible to avoid using backslashes to define paths in the filesystem, so `C:\srcdir\testfile.txt` is more easily written as `C:/srcdir/testfile.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested code, but is closer how I'd write it:

```
SOURCEDIR = 'C:/srcdir'
TARGETDIR = 'C:/targetdir'

Dir.foreach(SOURCEDIR) do |f|
  filepath = File.join(SOURCEDIR, f)
  if !File.directory?(filepath) 
    if File.exist?(File.join(TARGETDIR, f) 
      puts "#{ f } already exists in target directory (not copied)"
    else
      print "Copying #{ filepath }... "
      FileUtils.cp(filepath, TARGETDIR)
      puts "done"
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, your OS would make it even easier; Batch and shell files and OS-level commands are made just for this.

Answer (score 2):

`FileUtils` is a module, it isn't part of the Ruby core. You need to `require` it to use it, like this:

```
require 'fileutils'
```

This stackoverflow question explains how to move a file using FileUtils: [How do I move a file with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403239/how-do-i-move-a-file-with-ruby)

Here is the documentation for the FileUtils module for **Ruby 1.9.3**: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html